# How to link to a Git commit in Redmine after pushing

Tags: git, commit, redmine, git-commit

We have Redmine set up to automatically link commits with related issues if the developer properly tags if (such as `#Refs` or `#Fixes`).  However, we have had some commits that were pushed to the remote repo without those tags, and we now wish to connect them.  How can we do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add a link to a specific commit, simply add `commit:<sha-of-commit>`.

So if I were linking to a commit with a SHA of `d675f2e5cd6bd87f45246422a79b0c4b93f366c4`, then I would click on "update" and then in the notes section I would put, `commit:d675f2e5cd6bd87f45246422a79b0c4b93f366c4`.  You can also use the short SHA if you'd like.

You can follow the new link that you just created, which should take you to the repository section that contains that commit (if Redmine is properly set up to integrate with Git, which it sounds like it is).  From there you can click "Add related issue" and then enter the bug or feature number.  This will show a cool gray box with the commit message next to the bug notes when viewing the bug details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow very detailed answer... thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for :-D

Comment: You can also use * as "Referencing keywords" in Administration - Settings - Repositories. This way you won't need to specify "refs" and "fixes" each time (just the issue alone will add a related issue).